# How to route multiple components simultaneously in a single page with VueJs?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, router

Currently by selecting 'friends' tab inside the side navigation I also display HomeView. This happens even if ProfileView is selected.

What I would like to see is that when user selects ProfileView and then clicks on Friends, then FriendsView and ProfileView is displayed. When HomeView is selected first and then 'friends' is selected, then both HomeView and FriendsView would be shown.

I am trying the following but 'keep-alive' does not seem to do the trick:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginView
    },
    {      
          path: '/home',
          components: {
            default: HomeView,
            side: FriendsView
          }
        },
        {
          path: '/profile',
          components: {
            default: ProfileView,
            side: FriendsView
          }
        },
        {
          path: '/friends',
          components: {
            default: HomeView,
            side: FriendsView
          }
        },
        [...]

  ]
})
```

```
<section>
  <header v-if="!showLoginPage">
      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/friends">Friends</RouterLink>
        [...]
      </nav>
      <RouterView name="side" />
  </header>
  </section>
  <section>
   <header>
    <nav>
      <RouterLink to="/home">Home</RouterLink>
      <RouterLink to="/profile">Profile</RouterLink>
      <RouterLink to="/login">Exit</RouterLink>
    </nav>
   </header>
   <keep-alive>
          <RouterView/>
   </keep-alive>
</section>
```